jQuery Pointer over image (floor plan)
I try to place a marker over an image (floor plan) that will stick to that coordinates regardless if user zooms in or out, drags the image in zoom mode. I have tried but with little success to create a semi functional code that uses the click and touch events.
One can double click or double tap to add a marker over a floor plan and then should zoom or not the marker needs to remain in the same position. Imagine you want to have a marker where the light bulb should be, you add a marker at that exact position and then you can zoom the floor plan but the marker should remain where it was added, unless the user double taps / clicks once more.
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Zoom and Marker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
    <style>
        #image-container {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #image-container img {
            width: 100%;
            transform-origin: top left;
            transition: transform 0.25s ease;
            cursor: grab;
        }
        .marker {
            position: absolute;
            color: red;
            pointer-events: none;
            font-size: 23px;
            transform-origin: bottom center;
        }
        #zoom-button {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 10;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        #zoom-button i {
            font-size: 2em;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="image-container">
        <img id="zoom-image" src="c:\0877bd8f8386ae50ec097e8c7a6d4a29.jpg" alt="Zoomable Image">
        <button id="zoom-button">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-zoom/1.7.21/jquery.zoom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            let scale = 1;
            const maxScale = 5;
            const minScale = 1;
            const scaleStep = 1;

            let isDragging = false;
            let startX, startY;
            let imgX = 0, imgY = 0;

            let markerX, markerY;
            let marker = null;

            const image = $('#zoom-image');
            const imageWidth = image.width();
            const imageHeight = image.height();

            $('#zoom-button').on('click', function() {
                if (scale < maxScale) {
                    scale += scaleStep;
                } else {
                    scale = minScale;
                }
                updateZoom();
                updateMarker();
            });

            $('#image-container').on('dblclick', function(e) {
                if ($(e.target).is('#zoom-button, #zoom-button *')) {
                    return;
                }

                const offsetX = e.pageX - image.offset().left;
                const offsetY = e.pageY - image.offset().top;
                markerX = (offsetX - imgX) / (imageWidth * scale);
                markerY = (offsetY - imgY) / (imageHeight * scale);

                updateMarker();
            });

            $('#zoom-image').on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
                isDragging = true;
                const event = e.type === 'mousedown' ? e : e.touches[0];
                startX = event.pageX - imgX;
                startY = event.pageY - imgY;
                $('#zoom-image').css('cursor', 'grabbing');
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            $(document).on('mousemove touchmove', function(e) {
                if (isDragging) {
                    const event = e.type === 'mousemove' ? e : e.touches[0];
                    imgX = event.pageX - startX;
                    imgY = event.pageY - startY;

                    const maxX = (image.width() * scale - image.width()) / 2;
                    const maxY = (image.height() * scale - image.height()) / 2;
                    imgX = Math.max(-maxX, Math.min(imgX, maxX));
                    imgY = Math.max(-maxY, Math.min(imgY, maxY));

                    $('#zoom-image').css('transform', 'scale(' + scale + ') translate(' + imgX + 'px, ' + imgY + 'px)');
                    updateMarker();
                }
            });

            $(document).on('mouseup touchend', function() {
                isDragging = false;
                $('#zoom-image').css('cursor', 'grab');
            });

            function updateMarker() {
                if (marker) {
                    marker.remove();
                }

                if (markerX !== undefined && markerY !== undefined) {
                    const markerIcon = $('<i class="fas fa-map-marker marker"></i>');
                    markerIcon.css({
                        top: (markerY * imageHeight * scale + imgY - 23) + 'px',
                        left: (markerX * imageWidth * scale + imgX - 11.5 * scale) + 'px',
                        transform: 'scale(' + scale + ')'
                    });
                    $('#image-container').append(markerIcon);
                    marker = markerIcon;
                }
            }

            function updateZoom() {
                $('#zoom-image').css('transform', 'scale(' + scale + ') translate(' + imgX + 'px, ' + imgY + 'px)');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

On zoom, the pointer will not stick to the current click coordinates and it will also not display the pointer when zooming. The funny fact is that it will increase / decrease the pointer height on zooming in or out.
Could someone show me where I am doing something stupid?
EDIT:
The code now manages to keep the pin at the coordinates when zooming but if the pin gets outside the zoomed portion of image and you need to get to the pin, it will move
EDIT 2:
Since the direction was not the desired one, I used a plugin that could help achieve all requirements. Now I should be able to render a marker from the leafletjs image on the left on the exact fixed image on the right. Somehow, that doesn't work, the location of the marker is off and cannot understand why:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Map with Marker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        #map-container {
            width: 700px;
            height: 500px; /* Adjust height as needed */
            position: relative; /* Ensure relative positioning for the image container */
            overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow to prevent zoomed image on the right top */
            float: left; /* Float left for main map */
        }
        #right-container {
            width: 300px;
            height: 500px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            float: left; /* Float left for right container */
            margin-left: 20px; /* Add margin for separation */
        }
        #right-container img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
            position: absolute; /* Position the image relative to the container */
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        .marker-container {
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-container"></div>

    <div id="right-container">
        <img id="original-image" src="C:\\0877bd8f8386ae50ec097e8c7a6d4a29.jpg" alt="Original Image">
        <div id="marker-overlay" class="marker-container"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var map = L.map('map-container').setView([0, 0], 1); // Initialize map

            var imageUrl = 'C:\\0877bd8f8386ae50ec097e8c7a6d4a29.jpg'; // Replace with the path to your JPG image
            var originalImage = new Image();
            originalImage.src = imageUrl;
            originalImage.onload = function() {
                var containerWidth = $('#map-container').width();
                var containerHeight = $('#map-container').height();
                var aspectRatio = originalImage.width / originalImage.height;

                var overlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, [[0, 0], [containerHeight, containerHeight / aspectRatio]]).addTo(map); // Add image overlay to map
                map.fitBounds(overlay.getBounds()); // Fit map to image bounds
            };

            var marker = null;
            var markerOverlay = $('#marker-overlay');

            map.on('click', function(event) {
                // Remove existing marker if it exists
                if (marker) {
                    map.removeLayer(marker);
                    markerOverlay.empty(); // Remove existing marker in right container
                }

                // Adjust coordinates based on the current zoom level
                var zoom = map.getZoom();
                var containerPoint = map.latLngToContainerPoint(event.latlng); // Convert latlng to container pixel coordinates
                var imgContainer = $('#right-container img');
                var imgWidth = imgContainer.width();
                var imgHeight = imgContainer.height();
                var relX = containerPoint.x * imgWidth / $('#map-container').width();
                var relY = containerPoint.y * imgHeight / $('#map-container').height();

                // Add marker in right container
                markerOverlay.html('<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>');
                markerOverlay.css({
                    top: relY - markerOverlay.height() / 2,
                    left: relX - markerOverlay.width() / 2
                });

                // Add marker to map at default LatLng
                marker = L.marker(event.latlng).addTo(map);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Thank you!

What is the reason for not using Leaflet built-in DivIcon or ImageOverlay? Leaflet does intensive use of absolute positioning and CSS transform, as you have figured out. Trying to replicate it is calling for hard work.

Here's a snippet that calculates the scaled position of the marker:


/* Constants. */
const MAX_SCALE = 5;
const MIN_SCALE = 1;
const STEP_SCALE = 1;

/*
  Just keeping variables and some
  functions in one place.
*/
const state = {
  scale: 1,
  marker: null,
  /* Position - always to the original scale! */
  markerPosition: {
    x: null,
    y: null,
  },
  /* Removing marker data. */
  resetMarker() {
    this.marker = null;
    this.markerPosition.x = null;
    this.markerPosition.y = null;
  },
  /* Set marker at a position that matches the scale. */
  get setMarkerPosition() {
    return ({
      x,
      y
    }) => {
      this.markerPosition.x = x / this.scale;
      this.markerPosition.y = y / this.scale;
    };
  },
  /* Get marker position - always scaled! */
  get scaledMarkerPosition() {
    return {
      x: this.markerPosition.x * this.scale,
      y: this.markerPosition.y * this.scale,
    };
  },
};

/* Zooming in-out the image. */
const scaleImage = ({
  scale
}) => {
  jQuery("#zoom-image").css("transform", `scale(${scale})`);
};

/* Adding marker element to the DOM. */
const createMarker = () => {
  const marker = document.createElement("i");
  marker.classList.add("fas", "fa-map-marker", "fa-2x", "marker");
  return marker;
};

/*
  Updating the marker element. Always pass in scaled
  coordinates!
*/
const renderMarkerAt = ({
  x,
  y
}) => {
  jQuery(state.marker).css({
    top: `${y}px`,
    left: `${x}px`,
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#zoom-button").on("click", function() {
    /* Scaling logic: updating the state.scale value. */
    if (state.scale < MAX_SCALE) {
      state.scale += STEP_SCALE;
    } else {
      state.scale = MIN_SCALE;
    }
    /* Executing image scaling. */
    scaleImage({
      scale: state.scale
    });

    /* Only re-render the marker, if there is one. */
    if (state.marker) {
      renderMarkerAt(state.scaledMarkerPosition);
    }
  });

  $("#zoom-image").on("dblclick", function(evt) {
    /* Getting the position where the marker should go. */
    const {
      originalEvent
    } = evt;
    const {
      clientX,
      clientY
    } = originalEvent;

    /* Creating a marker if there's none. */
    if (!state.marker) {
      state.marker = createMarker();
      jQuery("#image-zoom-wrapper").append(state.marker);
    }

    /* Setting the marker position. */
    state.setMarkerPosition({
      x: clientX,
      y: clientY
    });

    /* Re-rendering the marker at new position. */
    renderMarkerAt(state.scaledMarkerPosition);
  });

  /* Removing the marker on click. Just in case. */
  $("#image-zoom-wrapper").on("click", ".marker", function() {
    state.marker.parentNode.removeChild(state.marker);
    state.resetMarker();
  });
});
#image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  /* Specify a fixed height for better control */
  overflow: hidden;
}

#zoom-image {
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  cursor: grab;
}

.marker {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  /* pointer-events: none; /* Prevent marker from capturing click events */
  font-size: 1.5em;
  /* Smaller marker size */
  /* transform-origin: center; */
}

#zoom-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Dark transparent background */
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* Rounded corners */
}

#zoom-button i {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="image-container">
  <div id="image-zoom-wrapper">
    <img id="zoom-image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200" alt="Zoomable Image" />
  </div>
  <button id="zoom-button">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </button>
</div>



I don't believe that this snippet is production-ready, but I think it demonstrates the concept quite good.
The main points are:

always calculate the position based on the client coordinates AND the scaling, so you always have a normalized pair of numbers to store (normalized to the image at scale = 1, for example)

when you set the position, you have to divide by the scale factor
when you get the position, you have to multiply by the scale factor



I hope it helps you solve the problem.

thanks for trying to provide this approach, but even using your code, the dragging in zoom mode should work, also the marker needs to remain at the same coordinates. honestly I think this is not even possible with jQuery alone
